# Use of cardinality attribute in @property annotation

Tags: aem, apache-felix

What is the use of cardinality attribute in `@property` annotation in apache felix scr?

Answer (score 0):

It is well explained in Apache Docs [here](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/scr-annotations.html#property), what is that you are not clear about?

> ```
> cardinality 
> Defaut: Depends on property value(s) 
> SCR Descriptor: -- 
> Metatype Descriptor: AD.cardinality
> ```
>
> Defines the cardinality of the property and its collection type. If the cardinality is negative, the property is expected to be stored
>   in a java.util.Vector (primitive types such as boolean are boxed in
>   the Wrapper class), if the cardinality is positive, the property is
>   stored in an array (primitve types are unboxed, that is Boolean type
>   values are stored in boolean[]()). The actual value defines the
>   maximum number of elements in the vector or array, where
>   Integer.MIN*INT describes an unbounded Vector and Integer.MAX*INT
>   describes an unbounded array. If the cardinality is zero, the property
>   is a scalar value. If the defined value of the property is set in the
>   value attribute, the cardinality defaults to 0 (zero for scalar
>   value). If the property is defined in one or more properties starting
>   with values, the cardinality defaults to Integer.MAX_INT, that is an
>   unbounded array.

It refers to what type of property are you storing and if it has single (SCALAR) value or multiple value (UNBOUNDED), read more in [scr-javadoc-tags](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/scr-javadoc-tags.html)